# Acceleration Or Momentum

Tags: physics

I have implemented gravity in my game using RK4, and have a function that calculates the new acceleration. I will also be implemented collision using impulse , so should i change the acceleration too impulse in my RK4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wondering what property to use as the primary one, I suggest *velocity*.

If you choose momentum, then RK4 must deal with mass; if you choose acceleration, collisions must deal with very small time intervals and huge accelerations; RK4 has velocity already, and since collisions are discrete events that *must* deal with specific objects and their masses, it's very easy to convert final momentum to final velocity.